# How to specify array indexes to be randomized?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have an initial combination randomizer, producing a randomized binary array.

```
np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 20)
```

The question is - is there a way to specify indexes to be randomized within the array?
perhaps anything from the numpy set of tools?
or would that be a specified loop?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want to use randomised indexes?  In the particular case of a random array of `0` or `1`, if the input array is random, shuffling it/randomising the indexes isn't going to make it more random... though that may not be your intent.

Comment: it is further multiplied by a power key, and then the array is counted via np.sum
such, provides a number, which is the required coefficient I want to influence to a certain extent

Comment: Could you provide an example input and expected output? If I understand what you're saying, you have (a power key? an array of power keys?) that you want to multiply and sum (sum of scalar product of binomial array with power key? dot product of binomial array with power key array?) in some manner?

Comment: `array1 = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 20)
row = np.sum(array1*power_key) `

array1*power_key
Out[7]: array([512, 256,   0,   0,   0,  16,   8,   4,   0,   0])

then sums it up into 796

Comment: Please add the examples to the original post, so it is more readable for others

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```py
# make the index mask how you prefer
index_mask = np.array([5,7,8,13,14,18])

# generate the randomizer for the complete index window
randomizer = np.random.bionmial(1,0.5,20)

# make your power key as you want
power_key = 2**np.arange(20)[::-1]

# mask the randomizer with the index_mask
result = np.isin(np.arange(20),index_mask)*randomizer*power_key

return result.sum()
```

Comment: yes, was wrong in the power key part. 
but no, it does provide a multiplication of arrays.
my initial question was how to specify the indexes within the array to be randomized.

`np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 20)`

this gives me an array with 20 indexes randomly chosen with prob. 0.5 to be either 0 or 1. 
What if I want to specify which of them to be randomized only? like only indexes 5,7,8, 9, 13, 14, 18

Comment: What do you want done with the not-specified indexes?